# Get name of OS in Photoshop script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Well, the header kind of says it all.

How do I, in a Photoshop script, get the name of the operating system?
I need it to determine the syntax for the save path of the files.

Answer (score 1):

The app.systemInformation property returns a string which includes the OS, among other system properties.

You can do something like:

```
var infoStrings = app.systemInformation.split('\n');
var os

infoStrings.forEach(function(str) {
    if (str.includes('Operating System') {
        var osNameIndex = str.indexOf(':') + 2;
        os = str.substr(osNameIndex);
    }
});

console.log(os) // Should output the name of the current OS
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to determine the syntax for the save path of the files, the name of the file system is possibly the most appropriate:

```
alert (File.fs);    // "Macintosh", "Unix", "Windows"
```

Information about `File.fs` and `$.os` can be found in the document [JavaScript Tools Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf) (p. 48 and 218 respectively).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to determine the os:

```
var fileLineFeed = "";

if ($.os.search(/windows/i) != -1) {
    fileLineFeed = "Windows";
} else {
    fileLineFeed = "Macintosh";
}
```

It works for me as my users are only using one of those two operating systems.